# Normal distribution with upper and lower boundaries?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I am working on the following problem:

> The scores on a Physics test follow a normal distribution with mean $70 \%$ and standard deviation $8 \%$. Calculate the probability of a student to score more than $85 \%$.

Does it make sense to have an upper boundary for a normal distribution? Which one of the following calculations should I do?

**TI-nspire CX command:** normCDF(lower boundary, upper boundary, mean, stdev)

**Option 1:** $normCDF(85, 100, 70, 8) = 0.030308$

**Option 2:** $normCDF(85, 9E999, 70, 8) = 0.030396$

Thank you.

Comment: The question is indeed poorly worded. It looks like you should clarify this with your instructor, unless it is possible to have a negative score or above 100%. While having a $<0$ score has a rather small probablilty and perhaps might be ignored, having $>100%$ is non negligible.

Comment: Note that using a normal distribution in such situations is always an approximation, as the real distribution is bounded. Here, the numerical difference between the two computations is small, certainly smaller than the error induced by the Gaussian approximation.